# Experience Forms Tracking Issue - alias should not be null or an empty string. Parameter name: alias

Tags: sitecore-forms, tracking

We are getting the error once we submit the `Sitecore 9.1 form`. This is happening when we enable the checkbox `Is tracking Enable` in Sitecore core form. 
and this error is not with Standalone role, only with `CD and CM server`.

**The error is:**

```
[ArgumentException: alias should not be null or an empty string.
Parameter name: alias]
   Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.RequiresValidator`1.ThrowExceptionCore(String condition, String additionalMessage, ConstraintViolationType type) +100
   Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.Throw.ValueShouldNotBeNullOrAnEmptyString(ConditionValidator`1 validator, String conditionDescription) +121
   Sitecore.Framework.Conditions.ValidatorExtensions.IsNotNullOrEmpty(ConditionValidator`1 validator) +41
   Sitecore.Marketing.Core.Extensions.ConditionValidatorExtensions.IsValidAlias(ConditionValidator`1 validator) +139
   Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.DefinitionManagerBase`2.GetByAlias(String alias, CultureInfo cultureInfo, Boolean includeInactiveVersion) +87
   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DefinitionCollection`1.get_Item(String name) +156
   Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.PageContext.Register(PageEventData pageData) +437
   Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Analytics.Tracking.FormEventsTracker.RegisterFormBegin(FormTrackingEventData pageEventData) +374
   Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Analytics.Tracking.FormEventsTracker.RegisterEvent(TEventData trackingEventData) +100
   Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.FormRenderingContext.RegisterFormEvent(FormEventData formEventData) +117
   Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Controllers.FormBuilderController.Index(FormDataModel data) +271
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +139
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__11_0() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +387
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +387
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__3() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +68
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +68
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +648
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +213
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +131
```

Comment: Make sure that you have deployed marketing definitions. This error says that page event is not found in Tracker.MarketingDefinitions.

Comment: I'm also having this issue on an instance of 9.0 Update 2 (upgraded from 8.2 Update 5). It's not worked since our upgrade, and I've reviewed all goals and taxonomies to verify they have aliases. I've also rebuilt indexes, link databases, and deployed marketing definitions. I've queried solr and verified the sitecore_marketingdefinitions index has values as best I can (I'm in unfamiliar territory). Hoping this will help someone else since this is one of the few results on the error out there :) *Sorry, I can't comment because it's a new account, but I really wanted to participate in this thread

Answer (score 1):

I credit Sitecore support for the solution, they pointed me to the two areas where I should look for missing items within the System node. To verify it is extremely helpful to have a vanilla instance of Sitecore installed for comparison (or at least a working instance). In my case, the `/Sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Page Events` node was missing several items needed by Sitecore Forms.

Check that you are not missing items in the sections below. Compare to a vanilla instance of the Sitecore version you are working with (mine was Sitecore 9.0 Update 2). If you have any custom goals or page events listed, verify they are built correctly or package them/ delete and test without them to identify the problem.

> /sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Goals
>
> /sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Page Events

As stated in other posts, make sure you deploy marketing definitions after making changes.